# iPhone SDK extract PDF text

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I used some Quartz 2D examples to extract text from PDF with the callbacks.

```
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "TJ", arrayCallback);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "Tj", stringCallback);
```

Referencing the code from here: 
[Reading PDF files as string through iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362393/reading-pdf-files-as-string-through-iphone-application)

But in some PDFs, I cannot get all string contents (and yes, it is string). How could I parse BT (begin text) and ET (end text) operators with a C function?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103281/pdf-file-text-reading-and-searching http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42%22

Comment: If you are ok to use an API, you can do it by using the method extracttextpdf of stamplin API.
http://www.stamplin.com/api/docs/extracttextpdf/