# How to integrate or Fetch multiple PDF's in an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

Hello, I want to fetch more then 500 pdf's in my iphone/ipad application . How can I do this ? 
Any tutorials and examples ? Please help

Thanks in advance 
Nivrit Gupta

Comment: You want to fetch pdf's via a web-service ???

Comment: no i want to fetch more then 500 PDF locally to develop  the iphone app

Answer (score 0):

**This would help you**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html

[Extracting pdf text in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960195/extracting-pdf-text-in-objective-c)

[Reading PDF files as string through iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362393/reading-pdf-files-as-string-through-iphone-application)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html

Answer (score 0):

Best API for downloading files from the server is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/).

You can set number of documents downloading using `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount`.