# Reflow PDFs for an iPhone screen (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, pdf, sdk, uiwebview

I'm currently making an iPhone app that has PDF viewing a crucial part of its functionality.

However many of the PDFs aren't iPhone friendly and require zooming and panning to read them.
Is there anything I can do to make them better whether with the PDF itself or programmatically? (I'm currently using a UIWebView PDF viewer by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflowing PDF can be extremely difficult to do, impossible in some cases.  Even Adobe [confesses to severe limitations](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7d19.html) with reflowing in its own viewer.  This is because PDF, like PostScript (and unlike other formats like Word or HTML), is a [**page description language**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language).

You will probably only be able to reflow **text only**, without graphics, and you will only be able to do so in those instances when it is possible for you to extract meaningful text from the PDF (**a non-trivial task** in itself in the absence of [tagging](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=6067), sometimes **virtually impossible**.)

Challenges you may encounter with non-tagged PDFs:

- scanned, non-searchable documents, may require you to perform OCR
- letters rendered individually, not as part of strings (you will have a hard time determining whether the PDF actually read `noted`, `no ted`, `not ed`, `n o t e d`, etc.
- multi-column text, inset text boxes etc.
- the mapping between text and font may be obfuscated, i.e. letter `b` may map to the font's `A` glyph and will render as `A` -- the only way to resolve this mapping would be to OCR the font, or rasterize the PDF and OCR the whole PDF
- etc.

Comment: My thought would be that HTML would be a better bet for a reflowable document.  You could exert a ton of control over a web view to change the CSS dynamically and the document would just reflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do, exactly, but I have some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927841/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-to-a-pdf-page-within-a-uiwebview) that goes into the details of programmatically scrolling a PDF document rendered within a `UIWebView`. My solution uses private calls, which will cause an app to be rejected, but it demonstrates the general principle.