# Multiple PDF pages and scrollview in two dimensions in xcode

Tags: ipad, pdf, ios, uiscrollview

Super noob here:

I am trying to create a scrollview that will scroll through a number of pdf's in a two dimensional array for use on an iPad. As if I tiled all the pdf's and wanted to be able to scroll from page to page by scrolling up/down/left/right. How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to read the PDF pages and write them as image contexts. The big problem here is that it you will use a mechanism to generate the pages lazily keeping a little buffer of advance.

The only thing I don't get is why you need a 2D array to store a PDF if this can be done with a 1D array?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have realized through much research that I will likely need to do what you did or something similar. For now I have converted the pdf's into png's. The reason I want a 2d array os that I want to be able to present a series of pdf documents in a non-linear manner.

Comment: Ok, but I am not sure if having a bunch of images is the best approach, as images consume a lot of memory. It would be better to render them lazily on the fly or your app's memory will blow. BTW, why of instead using a UIScrollView you don't use a UIWebView??? You would have an instant PDF viewer. This can serve as a guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927841

Comment: Thanks again for the info! Your links got me going in the right direction.