# How to link PDF "Page number" with UISlider?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uislider

is there a way to link PDF page number with UISlider ?

I am mounting pdf (100 pages) on the top of UIWebView:
I basically want to quickly jump between pages of pdf using UISlider - is there a solution to this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927841/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-to-a-pdf-page-within-a-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

First off, yes... you can have the UISlider send JavaScript to a UIWebView.

Second, I think you should use something else. Try this PDF reader library instead:

https://github.com/vfr/Reader/