# UIScrollView and paging touch events not registering outside subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIScrollView` with paging, just like the apple photos app. The thing with my implementation is that the touch and drag feature does not register outside the bounds of the `UIImageView` subview. So whenever I have to page, I am forced to touch and drag the image rather than in the blank area. Is this a problem anyone else has faced?

Comment: you might want to check this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973169/ios-develop-how-to-extend-uiscrollviews-scroll-event-responding-area/6973419#6973419

Comment: also this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844356/uiview-why-does-a-subviews-outside-its-parents-extent-not-receive-touches/5844395#5844395